expo init todoList error. how do i get around this to start my project?
trying to make a to do list using react native in VScode. I ran " npm install --global expo-cli " in my terminal. Then after the command runs I run " expo init todoList". After this run I get this error code in my terminal: " expo : File C:\Users\Bruissed Ass\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo.ps1 cannot be loaded because
running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

expo init todoList

  + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess



"
What should I do? I dont really know what I am looking at. I did some research on it but im a novice.
I went to the more information website on the error sheet. Although I didnt understand a single word.

what I read from the Windows documentation. The PowerShell was not allowing me to run the script in the terminal due to restrictions on the PowerShell. I enable these restrictions by opening the PowerShell and running " Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser ". this seemed to fix the problem in total.

open powershell as an admin.
Run the following command: set-executionpolicy remotesigned
